# Javascript: Functions and arrays as key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

1) In some other languages define function as parameterized block of statements, and on syntactic level javascript function also looks like this, until it's said that it can have it's own properties and methods.How can  it be syntactically represented as key/value pair? And where does function code live?

```
 var x = function(a,b){alert('Hi');};
    // x = { _code: "alert('Hi'), _arguments: {a:.., b:..,}}
```

here code and     arguments are my imaginary internal properties

2) If array is key/value pair, can i think that array indexes are just object keys?

```
var a = ["elem1", "elem2"];
// a = {0: "elem1", 1: "elem2"}
```

Comment: "If array is key/value pair". May be you mean object, not array?

Comment: Everything is a object in JavaScript.

Comment: Not clear, from perspective here, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can’t represent a function object as key/value pairs in the way you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: "Commercial Suicide" array is object and object  is key/value pair

Comment: Ryan, why?  There is simple chain  - function is object, object is key/value pair. For array the same. I'm trying to get better understanding of language, don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment that **EVERYTHING** in JavaScript is a object.

```
var arr = [

  function () {

    console.log("Well... Look at that.");

  }

];


var obj = arr[0];

obj();

var newObj = Object.assign({}, arr);

console.log(newObj);

newObj[0]();
```

Comment: You just notice that function is first class object(i guess) , this is not answer to my question

Comment: No... i used a function just to illustrate. I could have put anything in that array.

Comment: :) This is also not really an answer to my question

Comment: Your question is whether you can think of arrays as key/value. This simply illustrates that yes you can think of them that way... In JavaScript it's easier to just think of everything as a object.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. This was just one part of my question. Another is about functions. It's very weird to think about function as key/ value pair.

Answer (score 0):

> How can it be syntactically represented as key/value pair?

It can't.

The executable code of a function is not expressed in terms of properties on an object.

> And where does function code live?

That's an implementation detail of the JavaScript engine, not something that is exposed to JavaScript code in a standard way.

> If array is key/value pair, can i think that array indexes are just object keys?

They **are** just properties. See [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4):

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1. A property whose property name is an array index is also called an element. Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>. The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index;

… and so on.

Comment: "The executable code of a function is not expressed in terms of properties on an object."  That's a bit confusing. I didn't expect that i could change function code via some function property but as i mentioned that there should be some internal hidden property for complete picture.

Comment: @Coder007 — As I said "That's an implementation detail of the JavaScript engine, not something that is exposed to JavaScript code in a standard way."